Не работает API ключ для работы с Яндекс картами
Подскажите пожалуйста почему не работает API ключ для работы с Яндекс картами.
Создал ключ через кабинет разработчика, вставляю в запрос:
https://api.routing.yandex.net/v2/route?waypoints=25.234369457896325,55.280222457968712|25.234369457896325,55.401544758961258&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY

И мне выводит:

{"errors": ["Apikey rejected."]}

Никакие ограничения для ключа не делал


проверьте на наличие пробелов 2. точно ли скопировали 3. в кабинете разработчика проверьте активен ли ваш API-ключ 4. свяжитесь с поддержкой Яндекса


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

А домен точно совпадает с тем, на который запрашивался ключ?

А домен нужно указывать в ограничениях? Я ничего не указывал. Я делал всё вот по этой инструкции: https://yandex.ru/dev/router/doc/ru/quickstart

Если вы не указываете в заголовках запроса referer, то любое указанное вами в настройках ключа ограничение приведёт к ошибке авторизации. API Маршрутизации — платный сервис, следует как можно быстрее обращаться в техподдержку за уточнением причины, иначе вы напрасно теряете деньги. Почта: maps-api@support.yandex.ru.

Проверить работоспособность ключа можно, обратившись в поддержку. Первичная его активация занимает около 15 минут. В это время попытки его использования будут приводить к ошибке авторизации.
В случае платных сервисов, например при активации API Маршрутизатора, о котором идёт речь, после создания ключа необходимо выбрать подходящий тариф и оплатить его. Только после списания денег в оплату тарифа ключ можно будет использовать по назначению.
